# Jquery Post Not Processing file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am stil having issues with my code the file is not being processed when permalinks are set to anything other than default.

```
<div id="thanks" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Redeem Points</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact" name="commentform"  >
            <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
                  <input type="number"  valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
                   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

I thought the inital issue was the but when i turn permalinks off it appears to work ok I really dont no what the issue is here thanks.  The html above is in the file /wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer5/kids-dashbaord.php as well as the jquery below  i am at a loss.

> type: "POST",
>      url: "/bin/sendredeempoints.php",

```
<script>
$('#thanks').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        //Ajax Method Call starts here
            var points = $("#points").val();
        $("#send_btn").click(function () {
            var dataString = 'points=' + points;
            alert(dataString);//Remove this
            return false;//Remove this
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/bin/sendredeempoints.php",
             data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
             success: function (msg) {
                 $("#thanks").html(msg)
                 $("#form-content").modal('hide');
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("failure");
             }
         });
            //Ajax Method Ends
        }); //Click Function ends
    }); //Modal event Ends
</script>
```

Stop with the downvoting whoever it is.

Edit

**Got  A bit further**

added this to my functions but its still saying file not found :-(

```
function load_these_scripts()   {
      wp_register_script( 'your_script', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'js/redeempoints.js', false, false, true );
      wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));  
}

add_action("wp_ajax_php_function_name", "redeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_php_function_name", "redeempoints");
function redeempoints() {

   // Some stuff here
   global $wpdb;
 //  $result = $wpdb->get_results( /* SQL code goes here */ );
   // Do something with $result
}
```

#### You may only redeem the maxium points of :

" />
                      " name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />
                       Comments?

```
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

my js file

```
var formdata = $('form.contact').serialize();
var allData = {
   action: 'redeempoints',
   data: formdata
}

  jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json",
     url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
     data : allData,
     success: function(response) {
        if(response.type == "success") {
           // Do something
        }
        else {
           // Do something else
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: this is not a jquery post. 1e what do you want to post. 2e what goes wrong when running the script

Comment: this is a jquery post I am wanting to post a form to a process fiel please dont make silly comments likt this

Comment: @WimPruiksma nah what u did was just down vote ! not productive at all dont down vote on something u cant answe that is trolling

Comment: Sorry i didn't downvote. And if you don't want any help just say so.

Comment: @WimPruiksma my bad obv someone else who couldnt be arsed to help lest u did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. This is an ajax post. Using jquery post its a bit different http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Your question is about posting in jquery, not ajax. So lets modify your code a little:

```
    <script>
    $('#thanks').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var points = $("#points").val();
    $("#send_btn").click(function () {
                var dataString = 'points=' + points;
                alert(dataString);//Remove this
                return false;//Remove this

var url = "/bin/sendredeempoints.php";
var data = $('form.contact').serialize(),

        $.post( url, { data: data })
          .done(function() {
            $("#thanks").html(msg)
                 $("#form-content").modal('hide');
          }).fail({
alert("failure");
});


    });//Click Function ends
    }); //Modal event Ends
        </script>
```

Posting with ajax is a pain in the ass. Since there is Jquery .post() its very easy. Modify if it's not correct. Let me know if it helped.

I see you use `alert()`. Use `console.log()` instead. No annoying popups. you can see the data in developer tools console.

**EDIT2**

The error you get, means your url isn't correct. You are trying to post to a file instead to an url.
I suppose you have an index file or a file that includes other files. 
Enter some php code to the file that includes this script. 
The php script checks in the url for data and if its true.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['data']) AND $_GET['data'] == 'true'){
    //Go to your php file. or include it.
//EXAMPLE
     include "/bin/sendredeempoints.php";
//On the sendredeempoints you can do whatever you want with the post.
    }
    ?>
```

Change your var `url` to this:

```
var url = "YOURWEBSITE.com?data=true"; // or the easy one
var url = window.location.href + "?data=true";
```

Comment: Ok ill give it a try sorry i thought you where the one whom downvoted me their typical of some people not willing to help

Comment: No problem. My Jquery 1 year ago was crap too. Let me upvote this then

Comment: so u believe its the return false is throwing it out of the fiel

Comment: The return false is blocking your code yes. Remove it.

Comment: its still not working its taking me to the url http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/player-dashboard/?playerid=16-18-4500000&points=23&comments=32 of and not found ;-(

Comment: instead of refreshing the dialog :-(

Comment: Then your url is not correct. i will edit my answer for you

Comment: thanks wil if you can its a pain when it works in plane files :-(

Comment: Can you tell me where you wanna send your post to. If you want to send it to sendredeempoints.php how does your url looks when  calling the it.? Something like this? yoururl.com/sendredeempoints.php or something else?

Comment: its to the file sendredeempoints.php  for processing which is located in my root bin directory

Comment: Oke JQuery posts on the background. So the page won't refresh. i will edit  my answe rfor you

Comment: thank u my friend where would we be without stack :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you use AJAX alongside WordPress :)

First up, in your functions.php (or plugin file), you'll have to localize admin-ajax.php and register a JS file where you'll make the AJAX calls - looks like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_these_scripts' );
function load_these_scripts()   {
      wp_register_script( 'your_script', 'URI_OF_JS_THAT_MAKES_THE_AJAX_CALLS/scripts.js', false, false, true );
      wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));  
}
```

Then in your scripts.js you need to make the AJAX calls like this:
Use this instead of the "data :"

```
$("#send_btn").click(function () {
    var formdata = $('form.contact').serialize();
    var allData = {
       action: 'php_function_name',
       data: formdata
    }

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : allData,
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               // Do something
            }
            else {
               // Do something else
            }
         }
      });
});
```

The `action: "php_function_name"` actually tells WP which function to call but you also need register that well. Do it like this, back in your functions.php (or plugin file):

```
add_action("wp_ajax_php_function_name", "php_function_name");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_php_function_name", "php_function_name");
function php_function_name() {

   // Some stuff here
   global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_results( /* SQL code goes here */ );
   // Do something with $result
}
```

Make sure you register the function with both "wp_ajax" & "wp_ajax_norpiv" otherwise it will only work for logged in users.

Cheers

Comment: can you adjust ur code to working with a the form I include above and how do i update tables etc in functions.php i though doing db calls direct their was not allowed.I want to be able to update a database table within the php file

Comment: I just edited the code. I used var called allData to store the form values and in the PHP function I used the global $wpdb object to make the SQL call -- which can be either INSERT, SELECT or anything else. More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: what do i use as uri just a fodler location

Comment: what do i also place in my html <form action tag for this to work

Comment: for when i put action= "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"  its saying file not found

Comment: Adrain please see my got a bit futher coment mate

Comment: You can use "get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js' -- if the file is the template folder. You don't have to place anything in the action tag for this to work. You're calling the JS when a button is clicked - $("#send_btn").click(function () { /* My JS code goes here */  });

Comment: Just as a clarification. The form shouldn't submit at all. Your taking the information using jQuery and sending it to your PHP function via AJAX. Then you're interpreting the result and making changes based on what happens.

Comment: so what should i use as my form tag then ? how does one tell the form to call the ajax call

Comment: can u add inline example like u did with the functions please as starting to understand this finally ;-)

Comment: the JS var allData has an "action" field -- that's actually the name of the function you registered using add_action("wp_ajax_php_function_name", "php_function_name"); So AJAX is saying to WordPress run this action (the php function) and use these parameters (the form fields serialized).

Comment: im just asking how i call it thru the button click sorry for all the questions new to ajax post

Comment: I just edited the JS part of my answer to reflect that. When #send_btn is clicked the code runs and makes the call. Just make sure #send_btn is not a submit button. If it is use event.preventDefault(); to stop it from submitting.

Comment: Search for this in the code I posted above: "$("#send_btn").click("